# Error in converting from json to object when param exist

Tags: java, jackson

I am trying to convert from Json to `JsonParams` object with the Jackson lib, but I get the error of `UnrecognizedPropertyException` when the property `client_id` exists. Here is the error [1], the class that I use to test [2], and the `JsonParams` class [3]. Why I get this error?

[1] Error output

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "client_id" (Class org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JsonParams), not marked as ignorable
at [Source: java.io.StringReader@1eee4b8; line: 1, column: 81] (through reference chain: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JsonParams["client_id"])
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:53)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializationContext.unknownFieldException(StdDeserializationContext.java:267)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.StdDeserializer.reportUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:673)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:659)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializer.java:1365)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer._handleUnknown(BeanDeserializer.java:725)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:703)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:580)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2732)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1863)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Medusa.init(Medusa.java:67)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Medusa.submit(Medusa.java:355)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Medusa.runJob(Medusa.java:331)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.examples.MyWordCount.main(MyWordCount.java:146)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:71)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.run(ProgramDriver.java:144)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.driver(ProgramDriver.java:152)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.examples.ExampleDriver.main(ExampleDriver.java:38)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

[2] The class to test

```
package org.apache.hadoop.mapred.examples;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JsonParams;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
import java.io.IOException;

public class JsonToClassTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String content = "{\"output_path\": \"/output1-1443369483\", \"input_path\": [\"/input1\"], \"client_id\": \"1443369483\", \"type\": \"-map\", \"should_tamper_digest\":\"true\"}";
    try {
        Object params =  mapper.readValue(content, JsonParams.class);
        System.out.println(params.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

[3] Json params class

```
package org.apache.hadoop.mapred;

public class JsonParams {
  private String type;
  private String client_id;
  private String output_path;
  private String[] input_path;
  private String should_tamper_digest;

  public String[] getInput_path() {
    return input_path;
  }

  public String getType() {
    return type;
  }

  public String getOutput_path() {
    return output_path;
  }

  public String getShouldTamperDigest() {
    return should_tamper_digest;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "JsonParams [type=" + type + ", client_id=" + client_id+ ", " +
            "output_path=" + output_path + ", should_tamper_digest=" + should_tamper_digest + "]";
  }
}
```

Comment: From what I see you have no setters in JsonParams

Comment: Yes, I needed setters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add setters to you `JsonParams` class. It should give o/p as

```
JsonParams [type=-map, client_id=1443369483, output_path=/output1-1443369483, should_tamper_digest=true]
```